# How do you use NPM to get fontawesome pro css files

Tags: css, npm, font-awesome

I hope someone can help me here. 
We recently purchased a **font awesome pro license** and would like to use it on many **sub-domains**, but can't add each one under the services tab on the font awesome site to allow the CDN access. So we decided to have the files in our project using **NPM**. But so far it seems like it only downloads the JS version of font awesome, which makes sense if the project was built as a javascript application, but it's not. We currently use css version, and were wondering if NPM has a **font awesome pro css** version we can reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-brands
```

Have you tried above...

you need to add `npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/TOKEN`

Comment: I have, and it's the one that gives me the js files. I need the css files though.

I also have added the token script.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the answer on their site. This command downloads the pro css files.

```
$ npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webfonts
```